# Python - No linkea imagen jpg

Tags: python, imagen, flask, enlace

No linkea la imagen jpg.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código html de la imagen es el index.html.

Y la app apunta al siguiente directorio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté de todas las maneras posibles y la imagen no me la trae:

src="../uploads/{{ noticias[0] }}"

src="uploads/{{ noticias[0] }}"

src="{{ noticias[0] }}"

Si miro la consola del navegador el directorio pareciera estar correctamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El directorio templates está al mismo nivel que el directorio uploads.
¿Qué es lo que está mal?

Gracias,